# How to install Samba on Centos 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, samba

I am having some trouble when installing samba on Centos6.5.

I use this command:

```
sudo yum install samba samba-client samba-common
```

But I keep getting this Error:

```
Error: Package: samba-winbind-clients-3.6.9-164.el6.i686 (tejas-barot-alub-tv)
           Requires: samba-winbind = 3.6.9-164.el6
           Installed: samba-winbind-3.6.9-168.el6_5.x86_64 (@updates)
               samba-winbind = 3.6.9-168.el6_5
           Available: samba-winbind-3.6.9-164.el6.x86_64 (tejas-barot-alub-tv)
               samba-winbind = 3.6.9-164.el6
           Available: samba4-winbind-4.0.0-58.el6.rc4.x86_64 (tejas-barot-alub-tv)
               samba-winbind = 4.0.0-58.el6.rc4
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I see that I have the required packages, but how to I change the version of them, so I can install Samba on my server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution -

1. Remove any installed Samba versions: - sudo yum remove samba4-libs samba-common samba-winbind-clients samba-winbind samba-client
2. Install samba - sudo yum install samba
3. Test: service smb start

Answer (score 0):

Try Running :

```
yum clean all
```

then

```
yum install samba-winbind-clients
```

Comment: I get this: [root@node1 data]# yum install samba-winbind-clients
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
Package matching samba-winbind-clients-3.6.9-164.el6.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do ] It seems it is already installed ?

Comment: Try the updated answer if that works out.

Comment: I tried and got the same as before: Package matching samba-winbind-clients-3.6.9-164.el6.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do

Comment: I found a solution - 
1. Remove any installed Samba versions: 
 -  sudo yum remove samba4-libs samba-common samba-winbind-clients samba-winbind samba-client

2. Install samba 3:
 - sudo yum install samba

Test:
service smb start

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yum install samba4 samba4-client samba4-common
```

or see [this tutorial](http://lintut.com/easy-samba-server-installation-on-centos-6-5/)